# How should I include code samples in posts?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

What are best practices for including sections of Mathematica code in posts?

Mathematica differs from many programming languages because many of us use it in "REPL" (read-evaluate-print-line) mode, so output is interspersed with input, making it hard to copy and paste code. Are there any tricks to ameliorate this?

Comment: Could we make a mode that would accommodate the REPL style of the Mathematica notebook? When you highlight cells and right click, you get a "Copy As" option, could we leverage the options it has in that submenu for display on the site?

Answer (score 20):

Copying output from Mathematica can be tricky at times.  Here are some tips on making it easier:

**Copying:**

- Use `Copy As -> Plain Text`, or `Copy As -> Input Text` from the context menu to avoid copying (not really human readable) box expressions.
- If you copy only input cells, the In/Out labels will not be copied.  To select all input cells in a notebook, Alt-Click an input cell bracket.  (You can copy the relevant section to a new notebook before selecting input cells.)
- Whenever possible, make sure that the code posted can be copied back to Mathematica and evaluated.  But in some special cases it's good to show the formatted expression too, as a screenshot.  The [image uploader palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-easily-post-images-directly-from-mathematica) makes this very easy.

Unfortunately formatting (indentation and newlines) will get lost when the code is copied.  I do not know if there's a good solution for this (I'd be very interested!)

**Pasting:**

- When pasting back code to Mathematica, it'll get pasted into a single cell.  `Cell ->Divide Cell` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>) is a convenient way to break it into parts again.

---

**A note about In/Out labels:**

When I post code to be copied as a whole, I always avoid In/Out labels, as this is inconvenient.  But when I'm showing the process of doing something, together with the output, and commenting on each step, I prefer to keep In/Out labels to make it very clear what is the input and what is the output.

Comment: I use the `Code` style (Alt/Cmd-8) for input cells.  That way, the (manually applied) formatting is retained by copy-and-paste.

Comment: How about extending the `super-unbelievable-image-upload-palette` for copying to the clipboard the selected input and output cells and comment out the output ones as in @Sjoerd's answer?

Answer (score 11):

I usually edit away any In/Out labels that may be left during copying. I then comment out the output

So

```
In[108]:= D[Cos[x] Exp[x], x]

Out[108]= E^x Cos[x] - E^x Sin[x]
```

becomes:

```
D[Cos[x] Exp[x], x]

(*  
===> E^x Cos[x] - E^x Sin[x]
*)
```

Comment: I have not done this before, but I think this is a good pattern to follow!

Comment: I tried to do this, but I think I'm just too lazy.  What about automating it?  I'll try to do it eventually, but if anyone can do it now, please implement it and post back!

Comment: @Szabolcs Perhaps post this as a question?

Comment: OK, hope people won't get mad at me for a "give me the code" question :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs It might be interesting.  I see two lines of attack: 1) Modify output printing (using $Post or so) or the Output form. 2) At Cell level, modifying cell contents.

Comment: I would first copy the selection to a new, invisible notebook, then modify the output cells, then copy the whole thing as "plain text", then close the notebook (all of this done programmatically, of course).

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/484/programmatically-copy-code-so-that-all-output-is-commented-out

Comment: @Szabolcs and any graphics in the selection should be uploaded to SE of course  ;-)  you have done it before...

Answer (score 8):

I have taken to using a combination of QUOTE and CODE blocks.  That is `>` followed by five spaces before each line.  It's quick to type by hand, and I think it both visually and logically carries the meaning of output.

```
Range@9
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
> ```

Comment: And is easier to hit the shortcut for quote and code than typing `(*` and `*)`. Heck, I don't even type that thing anymore in *Mathematica*, as there is Alt-/!

Answer (score -5):

I find Sjoerd's way of presenting code a bit bloated.

Why not simply use `>>` for input and `<<` for output?

```
>> (*If comments are part of the pasted code, there will be no confusion*)
   Print["as to what's a comment and what's code (not that it was such a big problem...)"];

<< "as to what's a comment and what's code (not that it was such a big problem...)"
```

**Because the code block is not executable, since `<<` and `>>` are Mathematica functions.**

Comment: The whole point of going through the trouble of stripping out the In/Out labels and commenting the output was so that the whole code block can be copied and run in mma without errors. Although I dislike a lot of the other options, they adhere to this important requirement. Yours, complicates things in several ways. In addition to this block being non-executable, `>>` and `<<` mean specific functions in _Mathematica_, namely `Put` and `Get`. You can see that this is clearly unpopular. I urge you to delete this and remove these from your recent answers where you've been trying to popularize it.

Comment: I understand. I don't see the urgency to remove this post, though. I've edited it. I'll edit my other answers.

Comment: Sorry, I should've just said remove that from your answers. I had "delete this from your answers", which I changed to "remove these from your answers", but forgot to delete the earlier sentence. I can't edit it now to correct it, but please leave this post as is :)

Comment: No problem, I see that you've already edited the troublesome answer. I'm out of work.