# How to use Mathematica StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I have no idea how to enter formatted code (with clear indentation as in my notebook), or to copy a plot or table from my notebook to the group postings. I can't find where there are any detailed instructions on this.

Must I first Export a graphic to some graphic format and then import it to the group posting? What about formatted tables or Grid displays?

If I want formatted, indented code must I type it all in by hand?

Perhaps experienced group members have figured out fast and convenient methods to do these things?

I don't even know if there is any way I can ask this question?

Comment: In the meantime you may read the faq http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: You are still an unregistered user, first it is a good idea to register your account, then when you will be able to do more on this site.

Comment: Here is the editing help page and markdown for properly formatting posts: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome David! For posting images we have a very convenient Mathematica palette, located [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5/57).

Comment: For formatting you could look into Leonid's code [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2809/57).

Comment: If the code is meant for anything other than display, e.g. for others to actually use, then convert it to InputForm (Cell > Convert To > InputForm) and copy/paste that into your note. If you do anything that renders it non-cut/pastable then you decrease the odds that people will try it or answer questions that require trying it or altering it.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these suggestions have helped me. I could not find the palette to post images. After converting an Input cell to Input format I could still not make a proper paste into the stackexchange posting.

Comment: David, click on [this](https://github.com/downloads/szhorvat/SEUploader/SE%20Uploader.nb) to download the palette @Sjoerd was referring to. As for your second question, could you be more specific with "I could still not make a proper paste into the stackexchange posting"? What, precisely, is not working?

Comment: I clicked _this_ and all I got was a page that said this file contains potentially unsafe content. I copied the content of an Input cell, used Ctrl-K to get a place to insert code in the posting, pasted the code and only the first line of it turned into code.

Answer (score 2):

The basic post formatting tools are described in [Markdown Help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

mathematica.stackexchange.com (but not this Meta site) also has LaTeX support.  This allows you to use "Copy as LaTex" to include many tables and expressions from *Mathematica* in posts.  LaTeX must be wrapped in single `$` symbols for inline expressions and double `$$` for centered blocks.  You can for example select the output of `Array[Binomial, {5, 5}] // Grid`, right-click, and select Copy as LaTeX to get this:

```
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 4 & 6 & 4 & 1 & 0 \\
 5 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 1
\end{array}
```

When that code is pasted between `$$ $$` on the main site it will format as a matrix.

For posting images of other *Mathematica* objects or expression by far the easiest way is to use [Szabolcs's image uploader palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32/121).