# New SE-Tools - formerly known as SE-Uploader

Tags: discussion

I have completely revised our [old SE-Uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/187) and finally finished putting all together in a package called the [*SE Tools*](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools). Therefore, we can now provide additional features because the `` SETools` ``  can be loaded. Currently, the uploader palette is still the largest part of the software. I have put much effort in providing a [very detailed description](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/blob/master/README.md) about how it works. The most obvious change is the new layout

> [image: SE Uploader]

which makes it clear that it is really a tool for *Stack Exchange* in general, rather than for our community only. Additionally, I have...

- ...included the possibility to share Cells and Notebooks as easy as you know it from the image upload. The expressions are encoded in the PNG images itself and sharing them is as easy as including an image in your post. Please [read here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1520/187) the discussion about safety issues.
- ...revived the possibility to roll out updates and notify you when a better version is available. Every once in a while, or when you press the update button, your local version is compared with the online repository. If there is a new version, you will directly see a list of bullet-points about the latest changes and can update it directly.
- ...written an update/install procedure which works for Mathematica **version 8** or above. This will replace old installations with the most recent version and update the whole package automatically. Unfortunately, there seems an issue for Windows users, which I'll explain later.
- ...not only changed the layout, but ensured that the uploader palette works and looks good even on version 8.

## Installation and Update

The update routine [can be found online](http://goo.gl/rQtfHZ) in the repository and installing the *SE Tools* should be as simple as evaluating this file with

```
Import["http://goo.gl/rQtfHZ"]
```

The installer will check for old installations of `SEUploader` or `SETools` and asks you whether it can remove them. If your directories are clean, then it will download the latest version of the repository (the file [master.zip](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/archive/master.zip)), extract it and place it in your `$UserBaseDirectory`.

**Attention Windows users:** It seems, than *Mathematica* simply cannot delete certain files or directories, because it somehow locks them. If you get an error, although you clicked *Yes* when you were asked for approval to remove them, please delete the directory manually and report back here.

## Known Issues

- there is a upload limit of 1MB when uploading Cells or Notebooks
- the above mentioned issue of being unable to remove certain files that are being used currently under Windows
- in version 8 there is unfortunately nothing like `ProgressIndicator[Appearance -> "Indeterminate"]` to get a constantly moving progress-indicator and I hesitate to use something with `Dynamic[Clock[Infinity]]`. Therefore, when uploading Cells/Notebooks in V8, only a progress-bar will appear and it will disappear when the upload is finished.

**Please report all other issues that you find**

Comment: Probably might want to have the logo/image by "SETools" then, to indicate it is a general set of tools :)

Comment: I thought hard about this: The palette is for uploading only, therefore the name "Uploader". The package itself can and will include more functionality. To be honest, I later realised the the *uploading to imgur* is a feature of Stack **Overflow**. At least this is how I understood it.

Comment: Well, I'm adding stuff to it so it won't only be an uploading tool :)

Comment: In any case I don't really care what it is called...

Comment: I'm interested in this, but I'm also nervous about anything that automatically installs stuff on my system. Are you willing to add a manifest of the installation to your post? Also, what is the ultimate disposal of `master.zip` and any other temporary files generated by the installation process? Sorry to be so paranoid but that's the way I am.

Comment: @m_goldberg No problem. 1. `master.zip` is if you would click *download ZIP* on the [main repository page](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools). 2. Temporary files are: the downloaded zip-file, the extracted folder of this zip. 3. Before removing old files, the installe always asks you. After the installation it deletes the downloaded zip and the extracted folder without asking. Please look at the [installation file](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/blob/master/SETools/Installer.m), it is not long and quite readable.

Comment: Uploading images works well in 10.1 (Win), but selected cells don't seem to. The uploaded image looks remotely similar to an arrow. The following is copied to the clipboard: `Import["http://goo.gl/NaH6rM"]["http://i.stack.imgur.com/VcRa4.png"]`

Comment: @Jinxed Please review the documentation about [what the button Selected Cell](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools#uploading-code-cells-and-notebooks) does. If you want to upload an **image of what you see**, please use always the *Image* button. Just select a cell and press Image. The Cell and Notebook button is for uploading **code**. Just paste your the `Import` command in your clipboard into Mathematica and evaluate it :-)

Comment: OMG! Sorry. I was under the (wrong) impression, that "Selected Cell" would format and copy the code like [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2810/24763). My bad. :|

Comment: I have an issue to report: the pallette seems to be flickering/blinking every now and then. I am using Mathematica 10.1.0 on OS X 10.10.3.

Comment: @shrx Unfortunately, I already knew this problem since I was having it on OSX too. I tried to minimize the radius of action of the used `Dynamic` calls by narrowing down `TrackedSymbols` and it seemed it got better (it flickered every 1-2 seconds before that), but I'm not really able to tell where this comes from. If you look at the [palette code](http://goo.gl/LfRnz2) you see that visible elements are only a few lines of code (line 43-95) and nothing special is used. I guess I need to tear it apart to find the source.

Comment: @shrx I have found one possible source for the flicker. I used `Invisible` to hide the progress-indicator that is shown during the uploading of expressions. As it turns out this was a bad idea because against all better knowledge that *invisible dynamic content is not updated*, it forced a constant redraw. Hopefully, the OS X flicker is gone now. Please update to SETools version 127.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** I fixed the flicker-bug of the SEUploader palette

---

#### Fix for the flicker-issue in OS X

On my OS X 10.10.3 with *Mathematica* 10 the palette flickered from time to time. I hat the feeling that the flicker appeared very often when I had a stackexchange chat-room with a lot of traffic open in Chrome.

Lately, I stumbled over an issue that seemed to be the cause for the flicker. In the SEUploader palette, I used a simple trick to hide the upload `ProgressIndicator` when the palette was idle:

```
Invisible[ProgressIndicator[...]]
```

I used the same specs for both, the visible and the invisible indicator to ensure that the palette layout does not move/resize when the indicator is shown during upload.

As it turned out, the invisible progress-indicator triggered a constant dynamic update. Therefore, some simple test revealed that

```
Manipulate[
 {s, ControlActive["Why so busy?", "Relaxed as always"]},
 {s, 0, 1}
]
```

was always busy when the SEUploader palette was open and it seemed to introduce some weird flickering of the palette under OS X.

I replaced the invisible indicator with an empty, static `Graphics` of the same dimension. The update can be downloaded and the current version is 127.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I have a bug report: since recently, Stack Exchange is banning the use of the goo.gl address for the decoder. For some time I've been sharing notebooks by including the line

> `<sup>` Mathematica code through `Import["http:// goo.gl / NaH6rM"]["https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM9dN.png"]</sup>`

under the image, in plain case (i.e. no backticks) because it's shorter (note the spaces on the goo.gl link: even here, in a code block, it's trouble). When editing an old answer today, however, I was met with the following behaviour:

[image]

This is a reasonable step on the side of Stack Exchange, but it does break the clean behaviour of the SE Uploader (i.e. you click 'upload notebook for site', paste the resulting text onto your answer, and presto). Maybe the mods here can persuade Stack Exchange to whitelist this specific link? (unlikely to go through, as it leads to crufty code, perhaps?) Or maybe a more descriptive URL can be found for this file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug report about a plot that is not correctly uploaded.

I just updated the uploader by executing the above `Import` command (that I cannot reproduce here because of the shortened URL).

I have a notebook that only contains the following code:

```
g[x_, y_] := {x/(x^2 + y^2), -y/(x^2 + y^2)};
Manipulate[
 Show[
  ParametricPlot[{{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {c, 10 t}}, {t, -Pi, Pi}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}],
  ParametricPlot[g[c, t], {t, -100, 100}] ],
 {{c, -1.5}, -3, 3}]
```

and generates this plot:

[image]

Now if I select the plot cell and click *image* I get an image with a missing circle:

[image]

The uploaded image is also missing the circle:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am using MacOS 10.12.3 and Mathematica 11.0.1.0.

Comment: Cannot reproduce under Win7 64, Mathematica 11.0.0.0, image is previewed correctly.