# This community policy about open source applications written in Mathematica

Tags: discussion

I'm moving from programming middle sized application, intended for personal use and very specifics needs, to broader projects that can result useful for a generic user. I would like to release them as open source <s>(with no open source licensing: simply publishing the code)</s>. Can mathematica.stackexchange accep requests for cooperation, beyond the "one question - one answer" paradigm ?

Comment: There have been posts introducing new projects/packages that essentially boils down to: "Q: How can we do X in Mathematica?", "A: I wrote a package blah blah, here's a few examples, etc." Note that the answer here must be thorough and be appropriate for this site. If you were thinking of just dropping a link and asking people to collaborate, then the site might not be a good fit, IMO. You can try asking in chat.

Comment: More importantly: **"with no open source licensing:"** that might not go well with many people. Not sure why someone would collaborate with you for free if you retain all rights and the software is released under an unknown/non-permissive license. (I mean there's nothing/no one stopping you from doing it... I just don't think "look but don't use or modify" is in the spirit of open source except perhaps in strict semantics)

Comment: Here I really made a huge mistake in expressing my thought. I'm sorry.
I did not mean the opposite of "open soruce license". I  meant "with not licensing whatsoever". The spirit is "look, use, modify as you wish". Do you think that I should edit my question changing  "with no open source licensing" in "with no license whatsoever"?

Comment: I think words like "modify as you wish" could be subject to interpretation as well and also confusing. For example, "Ok, I modified as I wished, but can I now give this to someone else? Should I add your name and mine or only yours? Can I ask this other person to pay for it? Should they also share their source code?", Etc. A variety of licenses exist to answer these questions unambiguously.  You can take a look at https://opensource.org/licenses and pick one that you like. That would make things easy for everyone. I personally like to go with MIT license and is what I choose for my projects.

Comment: I see. I have been a bit childish; the MIT License, however, seems perfectly fitting my intentions.

Comment: You should probably use [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/)

Comment: Please, can you explain if WTFPL is a joke or not ? Supposing it isn't, I could consider it seriously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say, it depends. Usually, users don't announce that they now plan to write and publish some open-source projects. They just do it and we often find a way to incorporate them here.

I have myself started and/or maintained some open-source projects that have a Q&A here. You could look at

- [Can prettify.js be extended to support Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8959323/1078614) which ended in the syntax highlighter that is used on stackexchange and the Wolfram Community. Code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting).
- [Mathematica Plugin for IntelliJ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/187) which is my largest project, has [its own website](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de) and is open-source.
- [Our SE-editor buttons](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1043/187) which is open-source
- [Our SE-Uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1521/187) that was started by Szabolcs and that I extended and maintain.

There are other very interesting open-source projects that have an Q&A, for instance

- [MaTeX package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/76943/187) that lets you render LaTeX formulas in Mathematica graphics.
- [MATLink package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24478/187) to use MATLAB from within Mathematica

and many many more. You can find them on [PackageData.net](http://packagedata.net/) which is another project donated by a user here.

Comment: Thanks for you reply ! I didn't know about packagedata.net. I will inform the community of the existence of a project when a specific question will arise. Please, can you look at the comments above and suggest an  amendment of my question ?