# The editor does not let me put latex code from Mathematica

Tags: support, editing

In this question: [Calculating a parametrized maximum, as a function of the parameter](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175726/calculating-a-parametrized-maximum-as-a-function-of-the-parameter) I wanted to show the output of a Mathematica expression. So I clicked the expression and chose "Copy as -> LaTeX" and pasted it into the question between two "$$" marks. But the editor did not let me save the question. I got an error in a red square baloon:

[image]

I could save the post by deleting the "$$" marks, but now the code is seen as raw latex. 
What should I do?

EDIT: Here is the equation that I wanted to copy from Mathematica:

[image]

Comment: I think the restriction is only applied for users with reputation below a threshold.

Comment: You may want to report this to [meta.se] "Don't detect Latex as code", something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have edited this question of yours. While we strongly encourage to post "plain code" to show what you have tried, this is not required if you need to present specific outputs. For your case, it is perfectly fine to upload images because everyone can repeat what you did on their machine.

Regarding the uploading of cells and output as an image, I strongly advise you to look at our [SETools Palette](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/new-se-tools-formerly-known-as-se-uploader) that can easily be installed and lets you upload selected cells directly as an image. You only have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in your post and you are done.

Comment: Thank you very much for the edit.

Answer (score 4):

You really shouldn't use MathJaX to display code in a question posted on Mathematica.SE. You should enter code with markdown. Click on the question mark at the far right of the editor tool bar to get markdown help on secondary button bar that pops-up below the tool bar. The *advanced help* button the far right of help bar will give even more good advice.

#### Update

This update addresses an issue raised in a comment to this answer.

You don't need type code into an editor pane by hand. You can copy from a Mathematica notebook and paste it into the editor. This [meta-question](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/3066) will tell you how.

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture of the equation I wanted to copy from Mathematica. Is there a way to copy this equation without using LaTeX? Should I just type the entire equation in markdown? It is a lot of text.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi. I have updated my answer to address the issue you raise.