# SE Uploader started to fail. Unable to upload image to this site from notebook

Tags: support

In the last few days, I noticed the [Pallette  SE Uploader](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/new-se-tools-formerly-known-as-se-uploader)  keeps giving a Java error each time I try to upload an image.

[image]

I select a cell and click on Image button then choose **upload image to Stackexchange**

[image]

Then get lots of Java errors

```
Java::excptn: A Java exception occurred: de.halirutan.se.tools.SEUploaderException: IO Exception during reading StackExchange's source
    at de.halirutan.se.tools.SEUploader.getFKey(SEUploader.java:95)
    at de.halirutan.se.tools.SEUploader.sendImage(SEUploader.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568).
```

This seems to have started few days ago. It could be due to an update to windows 10, as I remember doing windows 10 update about a week ago, but I am not sure. May be windows 10 did an update to Java that causes this problem?

Any one getting an error on this also? I am using

[image]

And tried this in V 13.3.1 and also V 13.3. same error. This used to work OK before all the time.
My windows 10 is

[image]

I've also just deleted all of SETools/ folder, closed Mathematica, started it, and installed SETools again using the command

```
 Import["http://goo.gl/rQtfHZ"]
```

As given in the post about SETools in the link I have at the top, and tried again, and it still gives same error.

It could be something changed at stackexchange end also to cause this not to work any more. I do not know.

**Update**

Just now, 11 PM 9/22/2023, out of the blue, it started working again, and I am able to use SEtool with no error !  I have no idea why. I have not even restarted Mathematica or the PC.  This tells me it was a network issue, or stackexchange changed something.

**Update**

Just today, March 14, 2024, again out of the blue, it started to fail again. I now get this error

[image]

So something just changed. I think it is change at stackexchange as I made no changes to my Mathematica at all. Now SEupload no longer works.  Its been working fine before today. Do others have same problem?

V 14 on windows 10.

Comment: I get the same error in v13.3. Debugging a bit the code, it seems the upload is successful and SEUploader gets the link, but the response structure of Imgur probably changed, and SEUploader considers this as a failed upload. Also, note that there is already an [open issue](https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-SE-Tools/issues/3) at the corresponding GitHub of the project.

Comment: @Domen thanks for checking. Yes, it started to fail few days ago.  It still fails as of now. I did not know there is a github site for this tool. Good that someone entered issue on this. I hope this tool is still being maintained as it is very handy to use to take screen shots and upload them.

Comment: I used this tool for a bit, but then figured out there's even a handier way. You just take a screenshot (for example, Win+Shift+S on Windows), then paste it directly to the textarea on StackExchange. Image is automatically uploaded and inserted :)

Comment: @Domen oh yes, I know about this alternative and use it sometimes. But it does not work for pasting link to image in **comment**.  many times I like to add screen shot to a comment I make. With the SEupload tool, it is easy. But to do this manually, you'd have to make screen shot, save it to file, upload the image to some external site, get the link, then paste the link in the comment.  Takes 10 minutes to do vs., 10 seconds with SEUploader. Then have to remember to remove the image in the future from the external site.

Comment: for comments, I just paste the image in the textbox for answers and then copy the link and paste it into my comment ... :)