# What's the appropriate method to share notebooks and packages in this community?

Tags: support

I want to ask a question that concerns a moderately simple but long code. I think that it, placed all inside the question itself, would clutter the message and make the post quite unreadable. How can I attach a .zip file, containing a notebook and some packages, to the question ? Does the procedure raise disapproval for security reasons ?
I have read the post [SE-Uploader: Safety issues when sharing code](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/se-uploader-safety-issues-when-sharing-code)
but it is seven/four years old and may be a lot has changed since then.

Comment: Some people won't download files sight unseen for personal security concerns, whatever the official policy is, if there is one. SE puts long code inside a scroll pane, so a long code might not necessarily clutter a post. (Someone recently broke up their code with lines of "=====" between the functions, so that it wouldn't be hidden in a pane. Now that cluttered things. And it would have taken twenty copy-pastes to get the code, so I just skipped it.)

Comment: Can you, please, explain how to insert a scroll pane ?

Comment: You get a scroll bars automatically when the code is longer than $N$ line where $N$ is like 30 or so (or horiz. scroll bars if wider than $M$ characters). See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46816/modelling-hysteresis-with-a-differential-equation for instance.

Comment: Just a point of view... If I saw "a notebook and some packages" attached as a zip file, I would probably immediately skip that question altogether. For me, "good" questions are those that are about Mathematica code somewhere between "it's explicitly covered in the documentation" and "help me with this indefinitely long project to build the next killer app". If you can't formulate a question without referencing several packages, then I suspect you haven't really identified your challenge yet.

Comment: Is your question really five smaller questions? Then ask 5 questions. Is your question about managing packages? Then the actual packages don't really matter. Are you getting a mysterious message or unexpected result? Then find a minimal code example that produces the same behavior.